# Wolfram Cloud not working in any browser

Tags: 18.04, firefox, google-chrome, cloud

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and Firefox and Chrome with extensions UBlock Origin, HTTPS Everywhere and Privacy Badger. Whenever I want to open code on Wolfram Alpha or just create a notebook on Wolfram Cloud, the page loads indefinitly and never does what it should. I tried disabling UBlock but it changed nothing. Where can the problem come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. It has been solved when I accepted the cookies. Button is on the lower right of the page, easy to miss.

If you have a link to a workbook and the button does not appear (only a white page or similar), then first try to visit https://develop.open.wolframcloud.com, accept the cookies and reload the workbook.

[wolfram cloud cookie accept button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAR8H.png)

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly !